# Who is the girl in the limo?

Tags: plot-explanation, 21-jump-street

21 Jump Street scene, after Prom, where the baddies escape in limos and Schmidt and Jenko are chasing them in equally sized limos. But in their limo is some girl, drunk out of her mind, who Jenko recognizes, and then eventually kicks her out of the car during the chase. Who is *that* girl?

Comment: ***Plot-hole alert!*** Nice catch.

Comment: Don't know if it's a plot hole exactly, but it is an oversight. Someone should've just said her name, or whenever she wasn't on screen, all the other characters should've asked, "Where's Lisa?" :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Lindsey Broad](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2365442/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t18) as Lisa, a high school student and a friend of Eric and Molly. She actually appears in many scenes before that (when Jenko punches Sanders; at the party; and later on at Eric's place, where she asks Schmidt why he and Jenko don't look alike). However, unless I'm very much mistaken, you do have a point: I think her name *is only established in the Limo scene* and we never see Jenko learning it before that, we just assume that he did at some point.

Comment: You are right about her name being established only in the limo scene.